# How to load text (not binary) debugging informaton from a seperate file with GDB?

Tags: gdb, elf, debug-symbols

I have a ELF executable that looks like this:

```
$ hexcat hello
00000000:  7F 45 4C 46  01 01 01 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  .ELF............
00000010:  02 00 03 00  01 00 00 00  D7 80 04 08  34 00 00 00  ............4...
00000020:  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  34 00 20 00  01 00 00 00  ........4. .....
00000030:  00 00 00 00  01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 80 04 08  ................
00000040:  00 80 04 08  E2 80 04 08  E2 80 04 08  05 00 00 00  ................
00000050:  00 10 00 00  B8 04 00 00  00 8B 5C 24  04 8B 4C 24  ..........\$..L$
00000060:  0C 8B 54 24  08 CD 80 C3  55 8B EC 6A  01 FF 75 0C  ..T$....U..j..u.
00000070:  FF 75 08 FF  75 FC BA 04  00 00 00 33  C0 E8 D2 FF  .u..u......3....
00000080:  FF FF 8D 65  FC 50 E8 01  00 00 00 0A  6A 01 6A 01  ...e.P......j.j.
00000090:  BA 04 00 00  00 33 C0 E8  B8 FF FF FF  8D 65 FC 50  .....3.......e.P
000000a0:  C9 C3 55 8B  EC E8 0D 00  00 00 48 65  6C 6C 6F 2C  ..U.......Hello,
000000b0:  20 57 6F 72  6C 64 21 6A  0D 33 D2 33  C0 E8 A6 FF   World!j.3.3....
000000c0:  FF FF 8D 65  00 6A 00 8B  45 FC C9 C3  8B 5C 24 04  ...e.j..E....\$.
000000d0:  B8 01 00 00  00 CD 80 E8  C6 FF FF FF  50 E8 EA FF  ............P...
000000e0:  FF FF                                               ..
```

I have a file of symbol table information that looks like this:

```
$ cat hello.debug
rec 8048054 8048068 code write
rec 804808B 804808C string _tmp_2
rec 8048068 80480A2 code printl
rec 80480AA 80480B7 string _tmp_4
rec 80480A2 80480CC code main
rec 80480CC 80480D7 code exit
rec 80480D7 80480E2 code _start
```

I would like to use the latter when debugging the former; how do I feed that information into GDB?

(The actual program I am trying to debug is significantly larger; this is just a example.)

Answer (score 1):

> how do I feed that information into GDB?

I don't believe you can.

Your best bet is probably to feed that information into a tool that will create a new ELF file with a symbol table described by `hello.debug` (this should be fairly easy to do by generating an assembly file with appropriate `.set` directives ([documentation](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/as_7.html#SEC114)) and compiling/linking the result), and feed *that* new ELF file to GDB with `add-symbol-file`.